# Python multithreading and inconsistent output

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency

```
import threading

x = 0;

class Thread1(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        global x
        for i in range(1,100000):
            x = x + 1

class Thread2(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        global x
        for i in range(1,100000):
            x = x - 1

#create two threads
t1 = Thread1()
t2 = Thread2()

#start the threads
t1.start()
t2.start()

#wait for the threads to finish
t1.join()
t2.join()

print x;
```

Running this multiple times produces different output, some in the negative and some in the positive. Is it because the two threads are using the same global x? I don't understand why: shouldn't the net effect (output) be the same after all the dust settles?

Comment: Your operations are not atomic. You should use locks for correct results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not necessarily. Imagine the following sequence of events. We'll begin at a precise moment after the program has been running for a bit; both `Thread1` and `Thread2` are inside their `for` loops, and `x = 0`

1. `Thread1` has control. It accesses `x` to determine the value of `x + 1`; `x` is `0`, so the result is `1`. However...
2. Before `Thread1` completes the assignment, control passes to `Thread2`. `x` is still `0`.
3. `Thread2` now accesses `x`. It calculates `x - 1`, which is `-1`, because `x` is still `0`. Because of the unpredictability of thread timing, it manages to complete the operation, assigning `-1` to `x`.
4. Control now returns to `Thread1`. It has already calculated the value of `x + 1` to be `1`. It assigns `1` to `x`.

Both threads have completed an iteration, and the value of `x` should be `0`, but its actual value is `1`.

Answer (score 2):

This is a classic concurrency problem in multithreaded computing.  Each thread must read the current value of x from memory, modify it, then write it back. If thread 1 reads the value, then thread 2 updates it,  when thread 1 writes the value back it will cancel thread 2's update. This is why you should *always* use proper synchronisation constructs such as semaphores etc.

Answer (score 1):

It is a classical race condition. [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#Software) has a good explanation of this situation.